# Parse CSV files with different quoting (and a wrong one)

Tags: python, csv

I have to process CSV files (around ~500 000) in Python 3 which all came from the same source. However, for unknown reasons, some of them (a few minority) don't have the same quoting mechanism than the others.
Unfortunately, I have no way to distinguish a CSV quoting rule from the source itself (I can't make a rule based on the file name).

Here's the 3 kinds of CSV I have:

```
"field_A";"Field_B";"Field_C"
"";"john; the real one";"krasinski"
```

```
field_A;Field_B;Field_C
;john "the original";krasinski
```

```
"field_A";"Field_B";"Field_C";"Field_D"
"";"john;"krasinski;"2019-12-12"
```

I can parse the first by setting my quotingchar to `"`, the second one by having no quoting char, but I have no clue on how to process the last one, which includes fields that must be quoted, and fields that cannot be quoted (because of the single `"`)

Is there a way for me to deal with this different kind of files ?

In the end, I'd like to have the value `krasinski` only for the `Field_C` for example, but I either have `"krasinski"` and `krasinski`, or `krasinski` and an error.

All the solutions that came to me feel "wrong".

I'm running Python 3.8, and currently using [what appears to be the recommended library](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html) but I'm not committed to it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: you need to place conditions for reading these kinds of naming convention for the csv, or you can use split to split the naming conventions

Comment: Which I can't since I have no way to easily distinguish the kind of CSV I'm dealing with ?

Comment: you need to make some criteria for dealing with the kind of csv you have by simply placing the conditions , after that you can use split() to split them.

Comment: Could there be a rule based on creation date?

Comment: Are you sure the type of quoting from example 3 appears like that in the original files? Seems very strange.

Comment: The bad files are mixed up in the middle of the others, unfortunately date can't be used :/
I am sure, that's why it has been driving me crazy

Comment: What is your expected output for those three examples? Please [edit] your question to show that.

Comment: The expected output is already given in the question, for the `krasinski` example.
I just need the right value at the right place